# 'NoneType' object is not iterable while printing sql table results

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running a simple select statement. I want to

a) print out the values of each row

b) put the values into a python list

I try this:

```
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='PYTHON_SNOWFLAKE',
    account='aa',
    warehouse='aa',
    database='aa',
    schema='test',
)

try:
    con.cursor().execute('SELECT CONTENT_ID FROM table')

    for row in con.cursor().fetchall():
        print(row[0])
    print("Done", con.cursor().fetchall())
```

but while printing I get an error that:

```
Error 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I double checked the database and the select statement does return 2 rows, so it's not empty. What else should I try?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are creating a new instance of the connection cursor each time. you need to save it in one variable and just call it instead of creating multiple instances.

```
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='PYTHON_SNOWFLAKE',
    account='aa',
    warehouse='aa',
    database='aa',
    schema='test',
)
cursor = con.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute('SELECT CONTENT_ID FROM table')

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row[0])
```